# Validation Pipes in NestJS : @UsePipes(ValidationPipe) or @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, validation, nestjs

I previously saw these two syntaxes for UsePipes Decorator in NestJS tutorials:

```
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe) 
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
```

From what I understand, `ValidationPipe` is a class itself, where `new ValidationPipe()` just works as in all object-oriented languages and creates a new instance of ValidationPipe.

What should I use ? What is the difference ? Is there any special usage where one if preferable to another ?

Answer (score 3):

Both work fine as is. If you need to pass any options to the pipe though, you should use the `new ValidationPipe()`. Otherwise, Nest will see the pipe is a class reference, not an instance, and create the instance to be used.